# Postgres Function End Loop and return Error

Tags: function, postgresql, loops, record, plpgsql

I have tried to create this function but the system is returning a "LOOP error" and I don't know how to return 3 variables at the same time. I've tried hard to figure this out but I didn't find an answer anywhere.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION conta_relatos(fator_normativo integer, fator_determinativo integer)
  RETURNS integer AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
    vinculos_encontrados RECORD;
    rel_pri INT;
rel_sec INT;
rel_ref INT;
no_item INT;
tipo_relato TEXT;
BEGIN
    rel_pri := 0;
    rel_sec := 0;
    rel_ref := 0;    
FOR vinculos_encontrados IN SELECT * FROM "Vinculos" WHERE ("Vinculos"."Fator_Normativo" =   Fator_Normativo AND "Vinculos"."Fator_Determinativo" = Fator_Determinativo) LOOP
    no_item := vinculos_encontrados."Item";
SELECT "Fontes"."Tipo_Relato" INTO tipo_relato FROM "Fontes" WHERE "Fontes"."ID" = no_item;
--IF tipo_relato = "1 - Relato Primário" THEN 
   rel_pri := rel_pri + 1;
--ELSE IF tipo_relato = "2 - Relato Secundário" THEN 
   rel_sec := rel_sec + 1;
--ELSE IF tipo_relato = "3 - Relato Referencial" THEN 
   rel_ref := rel_ref + 1;
    --END IF;
    END LOOP;
    RETURN rel_pri, rel_sec, rel_ref;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
COST 100;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`OUT` parameters](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createfunction.html) to return a single row with multiple columns. The `RETURN` type is optional in this case, I quote the manual [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createfunction.html):

> When there are `OUT` or `INOUT` parameters, the `RETURNS` clause can be omitted.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION conta_relatos(
    _fator_normativo integer
   ,_fator_determinativo integer
   ,OUT rel_pri integer
   ,OUT rel_sec integer
   ,OUT rel_ref integer
   ) AS
$func$
DECLARE
   tipo_relato text;
BEGIN

rel_pri := 0;
rel_sec := 0;
rel_ref := 0;

FOR tipo_relato IN
   SELECT f."Tipo_Relato"
   FROM   "Vinculos" v
   JOIN   "Fontes"   f ON f."ID" = v."Item"
   WHERE  v."Fator_Normativo" = _fator_normativo
   AND    v."Fator_Determinativo" = _fator_determinativo
LOOP
   CASE tipo_relato
   WHEN '1 - Relato Primário' THEN 
      rel_pri := rel_pri + 1;
   WHEN '2 - Relato Secundário' THEN 
      rel_sec := rel_sec + 1;
   WHEN '3 - Relato Referencial' THEN 
      rel_ref := rel_ref + 1;
   END CASE;
END LOOP;

-- No RETURN needed, OUT parameters are returned automatically.

END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Call:

```
SELECT * FROM conta_relatos(1,2);
```

I also largely simplified your function. Among others:

- Use ["Simple CASE"](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-control-structures.html#AEN56435) for your assignments.
- Simplify two queries into one with a join.

The whole function could easily be rewritten as a single SQL statement.

Comment: Thank you so much Erwin! Your solution works perfectly! You help me a lot, I'm new with Postgres. Best regards from Brazil!

Comment: Dear Erwin. Just one more question: What I have to do to insert the conta_relatos function inside a complex select to create a view?

Comment: The system is telling me that the sub query must return only on column

Comment: @Britto: I suppose you open a new question with more information for that. You can link to this one for context if needed.

Answer (score 2):

To return multiple values at the same time, you'll want to specify `OUT` parameters and change the return type of the function to `record`.  See the documentation [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/plpgsql-declarations.html).  Make sure to call the function with `SELECT *` to get the parameters back as 3 columns.

Please update your question to include the error you are getting, and if I can help I will update this answer to address it.