# Rewrite function to not return a record type

Tags: sql, function, postgresql, record, plpgsql

I need so much to rewrite this function in a way that it doesn't return a record type. The reason is that I need to use that to create a view.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION conta_relatos(IN _fator_normativo integer, IN _fator_determinativo integer, OUT rel_pri integer, OUT rel_sec integer, OUT rel_ref integer)
RETURNS record AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
  tipo_relato text;
BEGIN

rel_pri := 0;
rel_sec := 0;
rel_ref := 0;

FOR tipo_relato IN
   SELECT f."Tipo_Relato"
   FROM "Vinculos" v 
   INNER JOIN ("Fontes" f INNER JOIN "Itens" i ON f."ID" = i."Fonte") ON v."Item" = i."ID"
   WHERE  v."Fator_Normativo" = _fator_normativo
   AND    v."Fator_Determinativo" = _fator_determinativo
LOOP
   CASE tipo_relato
   WHEN '1 - Relato Primário' THEN 
       rel_pri := rel_pri + 1;
   WHEN '2 - Relato Secundário' THEN 
       rel_sec := rel_sec + 1;
   WHEN '3 - Relato Referencial' THEN 
       rel_ref := rel_ref + 1;
   END CASE;
END LOOP;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
COST 100;
```

The function must return 3 `int` columns: `rel_pri`, `rel_sec`, `rel_ref`

Comment: I'm using Postgres 9.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make your query work with a function returning a composite type (record / row) and don't need to change that.
I misinterpreted the error message in your [preceding question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15035977/postgres-create-view-with-record-type-function) and updated my answer over there.

While we are at the topic of **rewriting your function**, this can be rewritten as SQL statement (as I [mentioned before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15030722/postgres-function-end-lop-and-return-error/15031072#15031072)):

```
SELECT COUNT (f."Tipo_Relato" = '1 - Relato Primário'    OR NULL) AS rel_pri
      ,COUNT (f."Tipo_Relato" = '2 - Relato Secundário'  OR NULL) AS rel_sec
      ,COUNT (f."Tipo_Relato" = '3 - Relato Referencial' OR NULL) AS rel_ref
FROM   "Vinculos" v 
JOIN   "Itens"    i ON i."ID" = v."Item"
JOIN   "Fontes"   f ON f."ID" = i."Fonte"
WHERE  v."Fator_Normativo" = _fator_normativo
AND    v."Fator_Determinativo" = _fator_determinativo;
```

To make it a *drop-in replacement* for your existing function, you can wrap that into an **SQL function**, which is probably a bit faster than what you have now:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION conta_relatos(
    _fator_normativo integer
   ,_fator_determinativo integer
   ,OUT rel_pri integer
   ,OUT rel_sec integer
   ,OUT rel_ref integer) AS
$func$
   SELECT COUNT (f."Tipo_Relato" = '1 - Relato Primário'    OR NULL) -- rel_pri
         ,COUNT (f."Tipo_Relato" = '2 - Relato Secundário'  OR NULL) -- rel_sec
         ,COUNT (f."Tipo_Relato" = '3 - Relato Referencial' OR NULL) -- rel_ref
   FROM   "Vinculos" v 
   JOIN   "Itens"    i ON i."ID" = v."Item"
   JOIN   "Fontes"   f ON f."ID" = i."Fonte"
   WHERE  v."Fator_Normativo" = _fator_normativo
   AND    v."Fator_Determinativo" = _fator_determinativo
$func$ LANGUAGE sql;
```

Comment: Thank you so much Erwin! You really solved my problem, I even doesn't need the function conta_relatos() anymore. As you said, it's possible to use a simple select. Now I have the view ready to use and running fasters than with the function. Best regards.